# lncli pendingchannels output: difference between `pending_closing_channels` and `waiting_close_channels`

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lncli

When plotting `lncli pendingchannels`, two of the outputs are oddly similar:

`pending_closing_channels` and `waiting_close_channels`. I have only seen my closed channels either as the output `closedchannels` or as `waiting_close_channels`. I suppose `pending_closing_channels` refer to the step previous of negotiation for cooperative close? or is it after, during the amount of confirmations needed to wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer for this by asking the [slack](https://lightningcommunity.slack.com/) community:

- `pending_closing_channels`: waiting for confirmation blockheight after cooperative closing and publishing on the blockchain (standard case)
- `waiting_close_channels`: closing request being processed
- 'pending_force_closing_channels': waiting for confirmation blockheight of unilaterally closing the channel (Commitment Transaction)